# Read custom properties of term with webservice

Tags: 2013, web-services, term, custom-properties

I need to get the custom properties of a term through Nintex.
Since it isn't possible to get this with the 3rd party tool, I thought about a connection to a webservice (this is allowed)
**So my question is:**
Is it possible to read the "custom properties" of a term with a default sharepoint webservice? If it is, what webservice should I use? (+ any examples?)